# Regular expression to match single json object from each line in a file

Tags: regex, scala

I am new to regular expressions!
I want to get the specific JSON object from the string which may consist more than one JSON object.
I have a similar line in a file as below,

Mon Jan 20 00:00:21 -0800 2014,

> {"cl":"js","up":"aaa","ip":"50.100.200.210","cc":"US","rg":"CA","ct":"CAA","pc":"94538","mc":807,"bf":"9d9b0900247ab80b9dc4c60013245fa36d8d4dc4","vst":"2074ae4d-9969-4103-9637-92a31ba8a108","lt":"Mon
>   Jan 20 00:00:14 -0800 2014","hk":["sub","hatch"]},
>   {"v":"1.1","pv":"cc4c68d2-54b3-4607-9578-619f68b97947","r":"v3","t":"f1951bc8","a":[{"i":2,"u":"u.jpg","w":800,"h":532,"x":198,"y":1655,"lt":"none","af":false}],"rf":"regex","p":"scala","fs":true,"tr":0.9,"ac":{"20722":1},"vp":{"ii":false,"w":1905,"h":955},"sc":{"w":1920,"h":1080,"d":1},"pid":7343,"vid":8}

I want to parse the whole string and extract the JSON object as JSON string which consists the key "pv" in the third column JSON object. There might be some lines which do not have first JSON object but time column and second JSON object in the line.

I found `\{([^{}]|)*\}` this from another post which is matching total first JSON object and partial expression of the second object! I need to get only second JSON which has "pv" key in its structure from the total line! Any suggestions for given expression to get only the third column!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the liftweb json library like this:

```
import net.liftweb.json._
val p = net.liftweb.json.parse("""[{"cl":"js","up":"aaa","ip":"50.100.200.210","cc":"US","rg":"CA","ct":"CAA","pc":"94538","mc":807,"bf":"9d9b0900247ab80b9dc4c60013245fa36d8d4dc4","vst":"2074ae4d-9969-4103-9637-92a31ba8a108","lt":"Mon Jan 20 00:00:14 -0800 2014","hk":["sub","hatch"]}, {"v":"1.1","pv":"cc4c68d2-54b3-4607-9578-619f68b97947","r":"v3","t":"f1951bc8","a":[{"i":2,"u":"u.jpg","w":800,"h":532,"x":198,"y":1655,"lt":"none","af":false}],"rf":"regex","p":"scala","fs":true,"tr":0.9,"ac":{"20722":1},"vp":{"ii":false,"w":1905,"h":955},"sc":{"w":1920,"h":1080,"d":1},"pid":7343,"vid":8}]""")
compact(render(p \\ "pv"))
res3: String = "cc4c68d2-54b3-4607-9578-619f68b97947"
```

The `\\` operator performs a search for the given key. See here for more info: https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json

Note - I've added square brackets to the start and end of the json string so that it is valid json..

Answer (score -1):

You could also use the native scala json library like this:

```
val p2 = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull("""[{"cl":"js","up":"aaa","ip":"50.100.200.210","cc":"US","rg":"CA","ct":"CAA","pc":"94538","mc":807,"bf":"9d9b0900247ab80b9dc4c60013245fa36d8d4dc4","vst":"2074ae4d-9969-4103-9637-92a31ba8a108","lt":"Mon Jan 20 00:00:14 -0800 2014","hk":["sub","hatch"]}, {"v":"1.1","pv":"cc4c68d2-54b3-4607-9578-619f68b97947","r":"v3","t":"f1951bc8","a":[{"i":2,"u":"u.jpg","w":800,"h":532,"x":198,"y":1655,"lt":"none","af":false}],"rf":"regex","p":"scala","fs":true,"tr":0.9,"ac":{"20722":1},"vp":{"ii":false,"w":1905,"h":955},"sc":{"w":1920,"h":1080,"d":1},"pid":7343,"vid":8}]""")

p2.flatMap { l => Some(l.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String,Any]]]) }.
  flatMap(l2 => { Some(l2.flatMap( m => {
    m.get("pv")
  }))
})

res37: Option[List[Any]] = Some(List(cc4c68d2-54b3-4607-9578-619f68b97947))
```

Comment: there is no native Scala JSON library after Scala 2.9